# Unable to import pyspark ml library

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, modulenotfounderror

when I tried to import pyspark ml library to run regression, I got the below error:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
```

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jpour/spark/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.base import (
  File "/home/jpour/spark/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.param import P
  File "/home/jpour/spark/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I'm unable to understand the issue with the import.

Comment: Can you add how are you running the script? Are you doing a spark-submit or is it a notebook? Also, environment details if you can (e.g. cluster type)

Comment: these packages have some prerequisites -- try installing them (e.g. - numpy)

Comment: I run spark by pyspark shell environment and in standalone mode.

Comment: Is it necessary that i install python and numpy in spark shell.

Comment: yes. you need to install whichever library that is missing. I think you should do a `pip install pyspark` which might install all of its depedencies